# how to get data type of a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Which function is used to get the data type of tensors in tensorflow in python? I need to define dynamic data types according to different tensors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the type using `x.dtype`, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x=tf.constant([1,2])
x.dtype
```

This prints `tf.int32`

Answer (score 0):

In case the tensor is a Pandas dataframe, use this:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

For a particular column, use

```
print (df['Prices'].dtypes)
```

Reference: [Link](https://datatofish.com/data-type-pandas-dataframe/)